# Accessing field in one Form to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code where 'Form1' launches another Form 'VDlgAssessmentsCustomization'.
Now, there is a private field called 'institutionId' in Form1 which i want to access within the launched form. Is there a way 'without' passing this field value to 'VDlgAssessmentsCustomization.Initialize()'?

```
    using (var vDlgAssessmentsCustomization = new VDlgAssessmentsCustomization())

    {
        vDlgAssessmentsCustomization.Initialize(OpenMode.EDIT, taskType, itemRow.CustomizationXML);
        if (vDlgAssessmentsCustomization.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // taskRow.customization_xml = lForm.strCustomizationXML;

            SetOKButtonState();
        }
```

Comment: Where do you pass the `institutionId` in the current code?

Comment: I am not passing it at present and want to access it within 'VDlgAssessmentsCustomization.Initialize()' without passing 'institutionId' as a parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: Well that would be a bad design (against Encapsulation paradigm). A better approach might be creating some service which stores that value so you can access it from both components. Or use another design patterns (based on the application type/architecture you have)

Comment: Please, take a look at these articles: [Transferring information between two forms, Part 1: Parent To Child](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548052/Transferring-information-between-two-forms-Part-1), [Part 2: Child To Parent](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548052/Transferring-information-between-two-forms-Part-2]), [Part 3: Child To Child](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548052/Transferring-information-between-two-forms-Part-3)

Comment: Accessing private field without sharing or passing is not possible obiviusly, but to share the member across the class, you can share the member or entire class ref in initialize methood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand you well, but seems you want to pass data between forms. In this case from parent to child and then from child to parent.

I'd suggest to replace `Initialize` method with one (or more) `VDlgAssessmentsCustomization`'s constructor(s).

For example:

```
//contructor #1
public VDlgAssessmentsCustomization(OpenMode om, int taskType, string cusXML)
{
    //here your implementation
}

//contructor #1
public VDlgAssessmentsCustomization(OpenMode om, int taskType, string cusXML, int institutionId)
{
     VDlgAssessmentsCustomization(om, taskType, cusXml);
     //do not forget to set institutionId!
}

//public Form's property to return custom xml
public string CustomXml()
{
    get => yourXmlVariable
}
```

Then in parent form:

```
using (var vDlgAssessmentsCustomization = new VDlgAssessmentsCustomization(OpenMode.EDIT, taskType, itemRow.CustomizationXML, iid))
{
    if (vDlgAssessmentsCustomization.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.CustomizationXml.Text = vDlgAssessmentsCustomization.CustomXml;
        //other 
    }
}
```